# Output function for fminunc in Octave

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I am trying to implement the Regularized Logistic Regression Algorithm, using the `fminunc()` function in Octave for minimising the cost function. As generally advised, I would like to plot the cost function as a function of iterations of the `fminunc()` function. The function call looks as follows -

```
[theta, J, exit_flag] = ...
    fminunc(@(t)(costFunctionReg(t, X, y, lambda)), initial_theta, options);
```

with

```
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400, 'OutputFcn',@showJ_history);
```

[`showJ-history` is the intended output function; I hope I have set the `options` parameter correctly].

But, I can't find good sources on the internet highlighting how to write this output function, specifically, what parameters are passed to it by the `fminunc()`, what it returns (if anything in particular required by the `fminunc()`).

Could someone please mention some helpful links or assist me in writing the output function.

Comment: You could also implement gradient decent or normal equation to get your intermediate values that should be a piece of cake if you got up to LR.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer to [the source code](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/fb940d48c6f7/scripts/optimization/fminunc.m#l156). Consider also this example:

```
1;
function f = __rosenb (x)
  # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function
  n = length (x);
  f = sumsq (1 - x(1:n-1)) + 100 * sumsq (x(2:n) - x(1:n-1).^2);
endfunction

function bstop = showJ_history(x, optv, state)
    plot(optv.iter, optv.fval, 'x')
    # setting bstop to true stops optimization
    bstop = false;
endfunction

opt = optimset('OutputFcn', @showJ_history);
figure()
xlabel("iteration")
ylabel("cost function")
hold on
[x, fval, info, out] = fminunc (@__rosenb, [5, -5], opt);
```